# How to include a javascript file with different type in the html markup?

Tags: javascript

Let's say that we have a file with **.js** extension. We all know that it's a javascript file, but let us assume that the file type is not the usual **text/javascript**, instead it is **text/anythingelse**. Also, I have a interpreter installed that can interpret the data in the **.js** file with type **text/anythingelse** and give me pure javascript as output. But the question is how can I include the **.js** file with type **text/anythingelse** in the html markup ? As :

```
<script type="text/anythingelse" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

is not seeming to work ! The interpreter is designed something like this :

```
const Interpret = () => {
 const el = document.querySelectorAll("script[type='text/anythingelse']")
 for ( var i = 0; i < el.length; ++i ) {
   // Interpretaion process start from here......observe the "el" constant
 }
}
```

So how can I do that ?

Comment: You may have to retrieve it via a network request instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Should I use AJAX ?

Comment: You definitely *can*, but I'm not 100% certain it's the only solution

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok then, if it's not the only solution, please let me know about the more solutions. Please add an answer.

Comment: I don't know, else I would've said

Comment: Read this article migh help : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download the file using XMLHttpRequest()

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", f_strUrl);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('origin',undefined);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";//use what matches your case
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var l_data = event.target.result;
            //process your data

            if(f_funcCallback != null){
                f_funcCallback(f_strUrl,imgData);
            }
        }.bind(this);
        reader.readAsDataURL( xhr.response);    
    };
```

you can check the details here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest